# How to hide image when resizing using max-device-width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, response

Need to have the img disappear when i'm viewing on a mobile device

```
 <div id="art">
<img src="../images/canO.jpg" alt="" width="500" height="500"/>
</div>

@media screen and (max-device-width:450px) {...}}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your css code, not just the media query.

Comment: @media screen and (max-device-width:450px) {
 img {
  display: none;}
 .art {
  display: none;}

Comment: edit your post to add that css there. In future questions, it's best to add all the relevant code so people can provide useful answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this  media query.

```html
@media screen and (max-device-width:450px) {
#art img{
         display:none;
    }
}
```

I don't understand properly  what you are asking. If it is not the solution what you need, please explain your question further more. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , hurried I wanted to write like this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JfLhb)

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px){
    #art img{
        display:none;
    }
}

or

   @media screen and (max-width:450px){
        #art img{
             visibility: hidden;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:450px){
    #art img{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:450px) {  .art img { display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the whole div `#art { display:none; }` or add a class to the image. Alternatively hide the images in the div with `#art img { display:none; }`

I would just use screen-width, like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {   
  #art {         
     display:none;
  } 
}
```